# Efficient semantic triples with Perl, without external db server

Tags: sql, perl

I have several semantic triples. Some examples:

```
Porky,species,pig // Porky's species is "pig" 
Bob,sister,May // Bob's sister is May 
May,brother,Sam // May's borther is Sam 
Sam,wife,Jane // Sam's wife is Jane 
... and so on ...
```

I store each triple in 6 different hashes. Example:

```
$ijk{Porky}{species}{pig} = 1; 
$ikj{Porky}{pig}{species} = 1; 
$jik{species}{Porky}{pig} = 1; 
$jki{species}{pig}{Porky} = 1; 
$kij{pig}{Porky}{species} = 1; 
$kji{pig}{species}{Porky} = 1;
```

This lets me efficiently ask questions like:

- What species is Porky (`keys %{$ijk{Porky}{species}}`)
- List all pigs (`keys %{$jki{species}{pig}}`)
- What information do I have on Porky? (`keys %{$ijk{Porky}}`)
- List all species (`keys %{$jik{species}}`)

and so on. Note that none of the examples above go through a list one element at a time. They all take me "instantly" to my answer. In other words, each answer is a hash value. Of course, the answer itself may be a list, but I don't traverse any lists to get to that answer.

However, defining 6 separate hashes seems really inefficient. Is there 
an easier way to do this *without using an external database engine* 
(for this question, SQLite3 counts as an external database engine)?

Or have I just replicated a small subset of SQL into Perl?

EDIT: I guess what I'm trying to say: I love associative arrays, but they seem to be the wrong data structure for this job. What's the right data structure here, and what Perl module implements it?

Comment: this is more or less how an index on a column works, yes.

Comment: So, is there a better way to do it in pure Perl?

Comment: Use objects instead of hashes. (By "efficient," I assume you mean efficient for you as the programmer, not in terms of CPU clock cycles.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Could you say considerably more about that? Wouldn't objects make things worse? I meant efficient in both ways. Obviously, I could (and have) created a loop to do the six assignments. However, I sense I am coercing associative arrays into something they were never meant to be.

Comment: Very simple example of using an object (you would have to implement the class yourself): `my $porky = Pig->new(name => 'Porky'); say $porky->name, $porky->species;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot OK, but how would I get a list of all pigs without looping through every single object I had defined?

Comment: What's wrong with storing them in an array? `my @pigs = ($porky, $babe, $dinner);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [RDF::Trine](https://metacpan.org/release/RDF-Trine)? It has DBI-backed stores, but it also has in-memory stores, and can parse/serialize in RDF/XML, Turtle, N-Triples, etc if you need persistence.

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use RDF::Trine qw(statement literal);

my $ns   = RDF::Trine::Namespace->new("http://example.com/");
my $data = RDF::Trine::Model->new;

$data->add_statement(statement $ns->Peppa, $ns->species, $ns->Pig);
$data->add_statement(statement $ns->Peppa, $ns->name, literal 'Peppa');
$data->add_statement(statement $ns->George, $ns->species, $ns->Pig);
$data->add_statement(statement $ns->George, $ns->name, literal 'George');
$data->add_statement(statement $ns->Suzy, $ns->species, $ns->Sheep);
$data->add_statement(statement $ns->Suzy, $ns->name, literal 'Suzy');

print "Here are the pigs...\n";
for my $pig ($data->subjects($ns->species, $ns->Pig)) {
  my ($name) = $data->objects($pig, $ns->name);
  print $name->literal_value, "\n";
}

print "Let's dump all the data...\n";
my $ser = RDF::Trine::Serializer::Turtle->new;
print $ser->serialize_model_to_string($data), "\n";
```

RDF::Trine is quite a big framework, so has a bit of a compile-time penalty. At run-time it's relatively fast though.

RDF::Trine can be combined with RDF::Query if you wish to query your data using SPARQL.

```
use RDF::Query;

my $q = RDF::Query->new('
  PREFIX : <http://example.com/>
  SELECT ?name
  WHERE {
    ?thing :species :Pig ;
           :name ?name .
  }
');

my $r = $q->execute($data);

print "Here are the pigs...\n";
while (my $row = $r->next) {
  print $row->{name}->literal_value, "\n";
}
```

RDF::Query supports both SPARQL 1.0 and SPARQL 1.1. RDF::Trine and RDF::Query are both written by Gregory Williams who was a member of the SPARQL 1.1 Working Group. RDF::Query was one of the first implementations to achieve 100% on the SPARQL 1.1 Query test suite. (It may have even been the first?)

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" is not really the right word here since you're worried about improving speed *in exchange for* memory, which is generally how it works.

Only real alternative is to store the triplets as distinct values, and then just have three "indexes" into them:

```
$row = [ "Porky", "species", "pig" ];
push @{$subject_index{Porky}}, $row;
push @{$relation_index{species}}, $row;
push @{$target_index{pig}}, $row;
```

To do something like "list all pigs", you'd have to find the intersection of `$relation_index{species}` and `$target_index{pig}`.  Which you can do manually, or with your favorite set implementation.

Then wrap it all up in a nice object interface, and you've basically implemented `INNER JOIN`.  :)

Comment: I'm still thinking there "should" be some Perl-implemented data structure where I only have to enter "Porky,species,pig" one time, and everything else happens "magically"?

Comment: like some kind of database, of relations?

Answer (score 0):

A single hash of hash should be sufficient:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $type, $value) = split ',';
    $data{$name}{$type} = $value;
}

# What species is Porky?
print "Porky's species is: $data{Porky}{species}\n";

# List all pigs
print "All pigs: " . join(',', grep {defined $data{$_}{species} && $data{$_}{species} eq 'pig'} keys %data) . "\n";

# What information do I have on Porky?
print "Info on Porky: " . dump($data{Porky}) . "\n";

# List all species
print "All species: " . join(',', uniq grep defined, map $_->{species}, values %data) . "\n";

__DATA__
Porky,species,pig
Bob,sister,May
May,brother,Sam
Sam,wife,Jane
```

Outputs:

```
Porky's species is: pig
All pigs: Porky
Info on Porky: { species => "pig" }
All species: pig
```

Comment: OK, but doesn't Perl grep go through a list one element at a time? I was trying to use hashes to avoid anything like that.

Comment: Ok, but **Why** are you trying to avoid anything like that?  Unless you have a specific need that you're trying to address, keep the code as simple as possible.  This improves readability and maintainability.  [**When to optimize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(computer_science)#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 0):

> *Or have I just replicated a small subset of SQL into Perl?*

It's pretty easy to start using actual SQL, using an SQLite in memory database.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                
use warnings; use strict;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite::memory:", "", "", {
    sqlite_use_immediate_transaction => 0,
    RaiseError => 1,
});

$dbh->do("CREATE TABLE triple(subject,predicate,object)");
$dbh->do("CREATE INDEX 'triple(subject)' ON triple(subject)");
$dbh->do("CREATE INDEX 'triple(predicate)' ON triple(predicate)");
$dbh->do("CREATE INDEX 'triple(object)' ON triple(object)");

for ([qw<Porky species pig>],
     [qw<Porky color pink>],
     [qw<Sylvester species cat>]) {
    $dbh->do("INSERT INTO triple(subject,predicate,object) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", {}, @$_);
}

use JSON;
print to_json( $dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT * from triple WHERE predicate="species"', {Slice => {}}) );
```

Gives:

```
 [{"object":"pig","predicate":"species","subject":"Porky"},
  {"object":"cat","predicate":"species","subject":"Sylvester"}]
```

You can then query and index the data in a familiar manner. Very scalable as well.

Comment: The OP specifically rules out SQLite in the question: "Is there an easier way to do this without using an external database engine (for this question, **SQLite3 counts as an external database engine**)?"

Comment: Yes. I'm saying SQL may have been prematurely ruled out. This solution uses an in-memory database and shows how light such a solution can be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing categories and values, such as name=Porky, and species=pig.

Given your example, I'd go with something like this:

```
    my %hash;

    $hash{name}{Porky}{species}{pig} = 1;
    $hash{species}{pig}{name}{Porky} = 1;
    $hash{name}{Bob}{sister}{May} = 1;
    $hash{sister}{May}{name}{Bob} = 1;
    $hash{name}{May}{brother}{Sam} = 1;
    $hash{brother}{Sam}{name}{May} = 1;
    $hash{name}{Sam}{wife}{Jane} = 1;
    $hash{wife}{Jane}{name}{Sam} = 1;
```

Yes, this has some apparent redundancy, since we can easily distinguish most names from other values. But the 3rd-level hash key is also a top level hash key, which can be used to get more information on some element.